# SQL Server variable DB as stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have an Application Database (A-DB) which imports from a set of Databases (B-set-DBs, (around 50 DBs)).
The user selects 4 DBs of "B-set-DB`s" from which he wannts to import into the A-DB for his application.

I wrote an stored procedure for the import (about 4000 Lines of SQL Code) with 4 hard coded DB`s of B-set-DBs and it works perfect.

So my question is how to make the imported Database names variable?

I can not use dynamic SQL for the whole 4000 lines, because im callin functions and other stored procedures, there are a lot of parameters and strings and definitions of temporary tables and supqueries of subqueries of sub......and a lot of other weird things.
(I know it all sounds ugly but i just have to get it to run, i did not design the whole thing.)

Maybe it is possible to define a synonyme at the first line of the import stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_storedProcedure]  
(@DBName_1 nvarchar(512), @table_name_1 nvarchar(512))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
set @cmd = N'create synonym DB_SYN' + 
        N' for ' + 
        @DBName_1 + --[A70_V70_V280]
        @table_name_1 --.[dbo].[UNITCHANGEMAP]
exec sp_executesql @cmd
...
SELECT * INTO A-DB
FROM DB_SYN
...
END
```

And afterwards work only with the Synonyms.

Or does anyone knows a way which will do the same?

BTW I am using SQL Server 2008
So i see all the 50 Databases in the Object Explorer of SQL Server.

Comment: There's no way I know of to parameterize database names - in the same way that you can't parameterize table names, column names, etc.

Comment: Put the sql in a field with a placeholder token for the db name (`use %%dbname%%` .. etc`, create an sp that loads the text into a variable, replaces the token with a parameter and then calls sp_executesql to run it?